# Get exit status of child process on background

Tags: c, fork, child-process

Normally, if I want the exit status of a child I just do:

```
int pid=fork();

switch(pid)
{
case -1:
/*Error treatment*/
exit(1);

case 0:
/*Child part*/
exit(0);

default:
waitpid(pid,&status,0)
WIFEXITED(status);
}
```

Then I have the exit status on `status`.

The problem is that, when the process is on background I obviously don't want to do `waitpid()` so I don't know how to store the exit value in status.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `waitpid` will wait for the child to exit whether it's in the background or not.

Comment: Either use the `WNOHANG` option for `waitpid` to peridically poll the status. Or catch the `SIGCHLD` signal to get a "notification" when a child process changes state.

Comment: @dbush That's the thing, I DON'T want to do waitpid because, since I want to the the child process on bg, I don't want to wait for it.

Comment: @walter, that's why you have to use `WNOHANG`. Read the man page.

Comment: @Devolus It didn't work, what this is doing is nit wait and always return 0 as exit status. What I need is for the program to continue and when the child on background finishes, to have that exit status in status. Now, status is 0 no matter what the child does.

Comment: If it's running in the background, it doesn't exit so there is no exit status. Please [edit] your question to clarify what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the child process has been spawned, the parent will need to call `waitpid` periodically with the `WNOHANG` flag.  Using this flag will cause the function to return immediately, after which you need to check the status to see if the process actually exited or not.

For example:

```
int child_done;
do {
    // do something useful

    child_done=0;
    if (waitpid(pid,&status,WNOHANG) > 0) {
        if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
            printf("child exited with status %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
            child_done = 1;
        }
        if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
            printf("child terminated by signal %d\n", WTERMSIG(status));
            child_done = 1;
        }
    }
} while (!child_done);
```